# using an .loc and If statment

Tags: python, if-statement, pandas-loc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WT47.png)

Use the .loc method, select the column rating for the rows of df where company_location equals "U.K."

Store it in a variable called uk_ratings.

```
uk_ratings = choco_df.loc[:, "rating"] 
if company_location == "U.K." :
print(uk_ratings)
```

I am used to using SQL not Python, so a little stuck, need help in where I am going one as this doesnt runn

Comment: What does "a little stuck" mean? What *specific* problem do you have?

Comment: Sorry should of say the above code I have writen does run and work, need to know where I am going wrong so I can fix my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pandas conditions are expressed as *masks* (`True` or `False`) over each entry. So, in your case, to select the rating for UK companies you should:

```py
# 1. Consider only the rows corresponding to UK companies
uk_company_mask = choco_df['company_location'] == 'U.K.'

# 2. Take the rating column as a whole
ratings = choco_df.loc[:, 'rating']

# 3. Mask to consider only UK companies
uk_ratings = ratings[uk_company_mask]
```

Indeed, this can be done quite succinctly as follows:

```py
uk_ratings = choco_df.loc[choco_df['company_location'] == 'U.K.', 'rating']
```